# Heoku Github actions deployement - CI/CD - Unable to push branch because the branch is behind the deployed branch

Tags: heroku, yaml, devops, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline with github actions for a nodejs application after testing it it should be deployed to heroku,
all the steps of github actions are executed successfully except for the last which is deploy to heroku.

The error I got is
[image]

"16s
Run akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.0.0
Created and wrote to ~./netrc
›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed:
›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:  ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Successfully logged into heroku
›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
Added git remote heroku
›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
▸    No images to push

```
        Unable to push branch because the branch is behind the deployed branch. Using --force to deploy branch. 
        (If you want to avoid this, set dontuseforce to 1 in with: of .github/workflows/action.yml. 
        Specifically, the error was: Error: Command failed: heroku container:push web --app dsti-devops
```

›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
▸    No images to push

›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
▸    No images to push
Error: Error: Command failed: heroku container:push web --app dsti-devops
›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.54.1.
▸    No images to push
"

And here is the .yml file I used

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try using newest version of akhileshns/heroku-deploy. I also ran into the same issue, I used newer version and worked for me.

Comment: thank you @jeewan
problem solved with akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.7.8
also in my case, I created a separate job for deployment to Heroku after finishing building